# TFVC pending changes without checkout in TFS Everywhere

Tags: tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

Using TFS everywhere. Editing files without "checkout for edit".
after it, unable to see edited files list in "TFVC pending changes" window.

Comment: Can you provide detailed steps and screenshots so that we can reproduce this issue at our side?

Comment: I have 2 repositories. once was created in TFS 2010 its named project A. upgraded the TFS server to 2015. another one is created in TFS 2015 project name is ProjectB. Mapped two repositories in my local folder.edit some files in local folder which was mapped from tfs server. now i want to commit files. Detect local changes option is available in ProjectB..this option is not available in ProjectA. see the screenshot which is posted in Answer. i want to commit files without "Checkout for edit " files  in ProjectA.

Comment: So you it works with Porject B but does not work with Project A?

Comment: And what's the workspace type for Project A, is it a server workspace?

Comment: Yes,Detect local changes option is not available in Project A.its local work space. Both projects has been mapped in different folders.seems issue with TFS version. any suggestion?

Comment: What are the options you can see under "Action"? And can you check if the detect local changes option displays if you change the workspace for Project A to server and then change back to local?

Comment: see all options under Action like displayed in screenshot except Detect Local Changes for Project A.

Comment: It sounds like that Team Explorer treats the workspace as a server workspace since a Server workspace has all the options except the "Detect Local Changes" option. Did you try the steps in my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if your project is Offline, that is the behavior when your project is not connected with the TFS.

1- **Right-click on the solution name right at the top of the Solution Explorer and select the Go Online option**

2- If that doens't help, please check your connections to the tfs through the Team Menu -> Manage Connections.

3- If still happens, try to restart the Visual Studio

Comment: Hi Zinov, I am using TFS Everywhere in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Team explorer everywhere. Try to check whether your project is offline:

[image]

Right click your project > Team > Return Online.

BTW, the project will be offline if you switch workspace to other that isn’t include that project.

Update:

Pending changes window > Click Actions > Detect Local Changes, then the modified file (tracked by source control) in current workspace will be included in Included Changes

[image]

Comment: Have some folders contain *.sql file.its not a project. Mapping into local folder.then edit files in local folder. Now check it in Pending changes screen. unable to see edited files. hopefully you understood my scenario..

Comment: @Mahadevan Does the file tracked by source control? If not, open team explorer > select the corresponding folder > Add Items to folder. On the other hand, check whether it in Excluded Changes (Detected Changes)

Comment: Local folder is controlled by online TFS . didn't listed in exclude and include also. but check out and edit a file then listed in checking pending changes window..i want to check in without click "checkout"

Comment: @Mahadevan In Pending changes window > Click Actions > Detect Local Changes, then the modified file (tracked by source control) in current workspace will be included in Included Changes.

Comment: Detect Local Changes option is not available in Eclipse TFS

Comment: @Mahadevan I added the screenshot to my answer, is there Actions in Pending Changes window? What's your TEE version?

Comment: starain-That option is unavailable in my tfs..TFS Server plugin version is 14.0.3.201603291051.

Comment: @Mahadevan What's your pending changes windows like? Provide the screenshot here. What's your eclipse version? Try to update the plugin to latest version.

Comment: same popup,but Detect Local Changes option is unavailable.Eclips Version is Neon Milestone 6 (4.6.0M6).Team Explorer Everywhere Version 14.0.3

Comment: @Mahadevan I downloaded eclipse Neon from here https://eclipse.org/neon/ and install TFS plugin 14.111.1, there is Detect Local Changes option. So try to update your TFS plugin from 14.0.3 to 14.111.1

Comment: Starain - TFS server was upgraded to 2015. "Detect Local Changes" option is available for other TFS project which was created newly after upgrade to TFS 2015.  Detect Local Changes option is unavailable in old projects which was created in TFS 2010.But Server was upgraded to 2015.any solutions for it?

Comment: @Mahadevan Could you check in changes through TF command (TEE CLC)?

Comment: not working in TF Command.seems issue with version of TFS."Detect local changes" is not working in TFS 2010.I upgraded server 2010 to 2015.